# HOW TO CREATE A GROUP BY AND ADD A NUMBER FIELD IN SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

I am trying to write a SQL statement that will take values from a substring that I have parsed out and then order them in a certain manner to mirror what I see on the front end of my screen. There is a longer reason in why I do this in that there are scripts that automatically take what I have in a spreadsheet and enter them into the front end of the program, but they must be setup in a manner that the program can read it... long story short, one of them involves a "PICK" column in which it uses to determine the number of "tabs" it will issue before it presses "enter"

Long story short, my data would look like this

```
SubStr(CONCATField, 1, 4) SubStr(CONCATField, 5, 5) SubStr(CONCATField, 6, 4) EffectiveDate ENDDATE
```

I sort by `EffectiveDate Descending`.

Say I have the following data from the following query

```
SELECT
    SubStr(CONCATField, 1, 4), 
    SubStr(CONCATField, 5, 5), 
    SubStr(CONCATField, 6, 4), 
    EffectiveDate, ENDDATE
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    XXXXX
ORDER BY
    SELECT 
        SubStr(CONCATField, 1, 4), 
        SubStr(CONCATField, 5, 5), 
        SubStr(CONCATField, 6, 4), 
        EffectiveDate DESC, ENDDATE DESC
```

Output:

```
FCCC T1234  P123  20190101 99991231
FCCC T1234  P123  20160101 20181231
FCCC T1234  P123  20150101 20151231
FCCC T1234  P456  20190101 99991231
FCCC T1234  P456  20160101 20181231
FCCC T1234  P456  20150101 20151231
```

I want to add a column called PICK that would arrange it like this with the number of the group like below.

SubStr(CONCATField,1,4) SubStr(CONCATField,5,5) SubStr(CONCATField,6,4)

```
EffectiveDate ENDDATE
FCCC T12345  P123  20190101 99991231 1
FCCC T12345  P123  20160101 20181231 2
FCCC T12345  P123  20150101 20151231 3
FCCC T12345  P456  20190101 99991231 1
FCCC T12345  P456  20160101 20181231 2
FCCC T12345  P456  20150101 20151231 3
```

[image: picure of what I am looking for]

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by SubStr(CONCATField, 1, 4), SubStr(CONCATField, 5, 5), SubStr(CONCATField, 6, 4) order by enddate desc) as pick
from t;
```

You can simplify the substring to `substr(CONCATfield, 1, 13)`, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot simplify my substring in my case bc it is actuall ymore like  3,4   12,10, etc.  I just added in simple number to make it work... meaning my field is acutally 70 characters and I really need about 15 of those characters in order to pull what I need.  But the ROW_NUMBER was it!  I knew it was simple so thank you Gordon!